# How to apply Plancherel Theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-inequality

Let f be a function on the real line R such that both f and xf are in L^2(R). Prove that f ∈ L^1(R) and the L^1 norm of f(x) is less than or equal to 8 times (the L^2 norm of f(x)) times the L^2 norm of xf(x).

I'm sorry I don't know how to use Latex to post the problem. The origional problem is here: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~bell/MA598R/advanced1.pdf. It's Problem 18. It's one of the problems created by a teacher to help students prepare qualifying exams of real analysis.

I think the purpose of the question is to ask students to apply Plancherel Theorem, but I don't know where to start. I know all the properties of fourier transforms, but I couln't relate them here. I think the trick of the problem is to break f into two parts, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Also, the form of the inequality is somewhat similar to the uncertainty principle, but I couldn't get any hints from the proof of the uncertainty principle beacause the hypothesis is different here.

I believe the question is not hard unless one knows where to start. I've tried my best and I'm still blind. Could anyone tell me how to do it? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an application of the Cauchy-Swartz inequality. For any $a>0$
$$\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}|f|&=\int_{|x|\le a}|f|+\int_{|x|>a}|x\,f|\,\frac{1}{|x|}\\
&\le\Bigl(\int_{|x|\le a}|f|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_{|x|\le a}1\Bigr)^{1/2}+
\Bigl(\int_{|x|>a}|x\,f|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_{|x|>a}\frac{1}{|x|^2}\Bigr)^{1/2}\\
&\le\sqrt{2\,a}\,\|f\|_2+\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a}}\|x\,f\|_2.
\end{align}$$
Choose $a=b^2\|x\,f\|_2/(2\,\|f\|_2)$ to get
$$
\|f\|_1\le\Bigl(b+\frac2b\Bigr)\sqrt{\strut\|f\|_2\,\|x\,f\|_2}\ .
$$
Choose $b=\sqrt2$ and square to get
$$
\|f\|_1^2\le8\,\|f\|_2\,\|x\,f\|_2\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize using this way to tell f is integrable. But could you please show me how to get the estimate like in the original problem posted?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Strangely enough, the same question was posed one hour before, with more or less the same answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692926/use-plancherel-theorem-to-prove-an-integral-inequality/692997#692997

Comment: @Etienne: I'm sorry the question I posted twice, because I posted the earlier one without logging on my account.

Comment: @Julian Aguirre: Thank you very much for your elegant proof. I was kind of nerd in solving these problems. I wanted to try to apply Plancherel Theorem because somebody confidently told me that I should do the problem like that, but I failed. It's just like there are three methods to prove Hardy's Inequality: Fourier analysis, Jensen's Inequality and nondecreasing rearrangement of a function. Hardy's original proof was using Fourier analysis. But if someone told Hardy to prove it using nondecreasing rearrangement of a function, I suspect Hardy cannot give a proof.

Comment: @Julian Aguirre: I was deeply impressed by your answer. This problem has tortured me for a week and I couldn't get asleep. I feel the more I learned, the less smarter I am. I mean, if I did the question just after I learned Holder's Inequality, I believed I could figure it out. Do you have some suggestions on how to learn analysis? It's a philosophical question, or maybe I should post another question? Thanks!

Comment: @Etienne: I just found I could not add comment on my first problem. I mean, if x>=1, |f|<=|x|^2|f|^2, which is integrable, so |f| is integrable on {x:|x|>=1}. I seldom think of the questions with Holder's Inequality, because I'm now learning something related to the behavior of function. For example, like using Jensen's Inequality can give an elegant proof of Hardy's Inequality, but if I study functions delicately, I can give another proof. Another example is the Caldron Zygmund decomposition can tell more information about Maximal functions, but most elegant proof is Wiemer covering lemma.

Comment: @user11211 You have $\vert f\vert\leq \vert x\vert^2 \vert f\vert$, but not necessarily $\leq \vert x\vert^2\vert f\vert^2$.

Comment: @Etienne: You're right. Thanks!